# Detecting a Card in a Scene with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Can someone direct me to some information about how to do the following:

I have a database of about 10,000 trading cards. Given an image from a iPhone/Android/WebCam, I'd like to find the closest matching trading card. I looked up some basic Haar based image recognition, but that requires training with many images with generally the same content. My program would have 1 perfect image for each possible match.

Now the input won't be scans, so the routines would need to handle scaling/rotation and cropping of some sort. But the entire image should fairly visible.

Any ideas, or thoughts? This is my first foray into the world of OpenCV, and it's interesting to say the least.

Comment: Have you succeeded? I'm trying to do something similar... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about SURF to detect similarities in images?

Comment: That's perfect...I found OpenSURF, and it seems to do exactly what I want. I can compare the card with the highest number of matches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone new coming to this post, there are two broad approaches.

The first is feature matching (which was mentioned above). The general idea is have unique points match to each other. OpenCV provides numerous types of feature extraction and matching methods [See here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html). This approach is good for identifying the desired object under various conditions (affine transformations, light conditions, scale).

The second is template matching. This attempts to find an image patch within a larger image. OpenCV has methods for it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). The is good for complex, specific objects that are not expected to vary.